# Cut and plot of data frame and repeat

Tags: pandas, loops, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, cut

I have one data frame which has **19939** which have two columns one is **DateTime** and second is **speed** and I want to be **cut into 225 rows and then plot all the sub-data** and after that in next step, I wanna go 226 and again cut and plot all sub-data and so on till 250. I tried by the **iloc[]** function but it is not working well can you suggest me some loop. and in last my data type is **float64**. I am new here to learn pandas.

Comment: how exactly did you try to use iloc[]?

Comment: df.iloc[:250] like this way I tried but it took a lot of effort so can you suggest me some loop then it will be better for me.